# Representing drop down list values in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, django, database-design

I need to have several forms with drop-down lists using `select` tags. There are two options I have for representing the selected choice in each list:

1. Store the choice as a string or integer.
2. Store all possible choices for a particular list in a separate table, and then use a foreign key from the main table to this table.

For instance, one list will ask the user for the college that he attends. The user can either select one of the choices in the list, or select "Other" and enter a different value in an input box.

Another list will ask how many miles he has driven in the last year. The options would be of the form "0-100 miles", "100-500 miles", "500-1000 miles", and so on. If I use option 1, I could either store the entire string, or a short version of the string, or an integer. In the latter two options, I will manually convert the value to the display value.

I'm leaning towards option 2, but want to avoid having to change everything later. The only issue I've run into with this options is that I have to populate the database with the initial values for each table (I'm using Django and can use fixtures).

Since this is so common, which option do people tend to use? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Use a normalized design.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I'm familiar with normalization, which would correspond to Option 2. What I'm not familiar with is working on a large web application and intricacies people run into in production, not just at the database schema level but also the application code and data management.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely option 2.

1. Normalize everything.
2. Measure query performance.
3. Use caching or denormalize only when you notice poor performance results.